# Security of a given hash function

Tags: hash, collision-resistance, provable-security

We have a message denoted $M$. Let us suppose that we have a collision-resistant hash function $h_0$ with output length $n$. We then consider two other independent (different) hash functions $h_1$ and $h_2$, with output length $n/2$. For instance, we can choose SHA-256 for $h_0$, and SHA-256 with a truncated output (128 bits) for $h_1$ and $h_2$. Note that $h_1$ and $h_2$ are obtained by domain separation, i.e. $h_1=\operatorname{lsb}_{128}(\mathrm{SHA256}(M\| 1))$ and $h_2=\operatorname{lsb}_{128}(\mathrm{SHA256}(M\|2))$.

We now consider the hash function $h_3$: 
$$h_3(M)=h_1(h_0(M)) \| h_2(h_0(M))$$

I have read that the concatenation of two independent hash functions appied on the same message does not increase the security when the message is long. What about the above $h_3$ function, when compared to $h_0$? In terms of collision-resistance and second-preimage resistance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**$h_3$ is at most as collision and 2nd-preimage resistant as $h_0$.**

Proof:
Suppose we have a collision for $h_0$, that is, we know $x\neq y$ with $h_0(x)=h_0(y)=h$. Now observe that $h_3(x)=h_3(y)$ as follows: $$h_3(x)=h_1(h_0(x))\parallel h_2(h_0(x))=h_1(h)\parallel h_2(h)=h_1(h_0(y))\parallel h_2(h_0(y))=h_3(y)$$

---

Now that we have established that $h_3$ cannot be more secure than $h_0$, let's look at the "lower bound". Let $c_i$ be the boolean variable that indicates that a collision on hash function $h_i$ is known. Then the following holds:
$$c_3\rightarrow c_0\oplus(c_1\land c_2)$$
(with $\oplus$ denoting XOR)

That is, $h_3$ is at least as secure as $h_0$ *or* ($h_1$ *and* $h_2$). This assumes there are no subtle interactions between the hash functions which would facilitate a structure-lead collision search.

Suppose we have a collision on $h_3$, that is we know $x\neq y$ such that $h_3(x)=h_3(y)$. $h_3(x)=h_3(y)$ implies that $h_1(h_0(x))=h_1(h_0(y))$ and $h_2(h_0(x))=h_2(h_0(y))$ (by simple decomposition) and so we would have found a collision on $h_1$ with the values $h_0(x)$ and $h_0(y)$ and a collision on $h_2$ *with the same values*. This assumes that $h_0(x)\neq h_0(y)$ is allowed to be called a proper collision. If this is not the case we would have found a collision on $h_0$ instead. So we have $c_0\oplus (c_1\land c_2)$ being true, deduced from $c_3$ being true.

Actually the right-side of the found collision is worth "more" than a normal collision on a hash function. Because we have found a collision on *both* hash functions, which is equivalent to finding a collision on $h'(M)=h_1(M)\parallel h_2(M)$ which with the constraints given in the question has $n/2$ bit security.

---

**So what does all of the above mean?**

- If you can break $h_0$ you can break $h_3$.
- If you can break $h_3$ you can either break $h'$ or $h_0$.
- If either $h_1$ *or* $h_2$ is a permutation, then breaking $h_3$ is exactly as hard as breaking $h_0$.
- If you can break $h'$ you can trivially break $h_1$ *and* $h_2$.
- Two "normal" collisions on $h_1,h_2$ are very likely not sufficient to break $h'$.
- A collision on $h'$ very likely does not yield a collision on $h_3$ (because you would still need to find a pre-image with respect to $h_0$).
- If $h_0,h_1,h_2$ lack structural weaknesses, $2^{n/2}$ operations are required to break $h_3$ (which is the expected value).

*Reading hint for the uninitiated: "if you can break x then you can [logical formula involving breaks of $y_i$]" needs to be negated on both sides and then the sides need to be swapped for a security statement. That is "if [negated logical formula] is secure, so is x".*

Comment: Thank you SEJPM. what about a lower bound? I suspect a decrease in security since the collision resistance of $h_1$ and $h_2$ are reduced.

Comment: @Adam54, I'd have to run through the math. Yes, we can find a collision in either in an expected $2^{64}$ calls to the hash function, so we can find a collision in both in $2^{65}$ calls, but those collisions will (with very high probability) not have the same input, so that would not result in a collision on $h_3$. To get that, we would need multiple collisions on $h_1$ and $h_2$. We would need enough collisions on both to have a high probability of having a collision from the same input under both.

Comment: @mikeazo If you think about it, finding the same collision for two hash functions is equivalent to finding a collision on the concatenation of the functions. Which would imply $2^{128}$ work in this case as the output of the concatenation is 256-bit.

Comment: @SEJPM, that is what I was assuming, but I wanted to make sure. I'm pretty sure we had a question on here once about finding multiple collisions. I.e., how many calls to the hash function do we need to have $k$ collisions? Can't find it at the moment.

Comment: @SEJPM Thank you very much for your answer. I am not sure, I think that I have understood. What is the conclusion of your second paragraph? Can we say that $h_3$ is as secure as $h_0$? The first comment of mikeazo suggests that we should find a huge number of collisions for $h_1$ and $h_2$ in order to find a collision for $h_3$. How can we estimate the overall number of calls? If we want to conclude that $h_3$ has the same collision resistance than $h_0$, we should prove that the "overall" number of calls is about $2^{128}$? Right?

Comment: @Adam54, I finally found the question and answer I was thinking of. [*How much work is required to detect multiple collisions for a hash function?*](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/22551/how-much-work-is-required-to-detect-multiple-collisions-for-a-hash-function). That should be useful.

Comment: @mikeazo Thank you for the link. If I understand, we need to find multiple collisions for $h_1$, for instance $h_1(a_1)=h_1(b_1)$, $h_1(a_2)=h_1(b_2))$, ..., $h_1(a_k)=h_1(b_k)$, and the same work for $h_2$, for instance $h_2(c_1)=h_2(d_1)$, $h_2(c_2)=h_2(d_2)$, ..., $h_2(c_{k'})=h_2(d_{k'})$, and finally hope for the existence of integers $i$ and $i'$ such that we have both $a_i=c_{i'}$ and $b_i=d_{i'}$. The link you have provided is interesting since it shows that finding multiple collisions is faster than expected, but we still need to estimate $k$ and $k'$.

Comment: @Adam54, that is exactly what I had in mind. My guess is that $k$ will be large enough that attacking $h_3$ directly is more efficient (or no less efficient).

Comment: @Adam54 no, we cannot say that $h_3$ is as secure as $h_0$ in general. We can only say that if $h_1$ or $h_2$ are actually permutations (instead of hash functions). Against brute-force attacks, this scheme offers the same security as $h_0$ (ie $n/2$ bits). Against structural attacks, you either need to find one on $h_0$ (first paragraph) or find one on $h'\circ h_0$ which very likely is harder than finding one on $h'$ which is much harder than breaking each hash individually.